# Form validation rule MS-Access 2007

Tags: validation, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a simple form that gets used to enter information into a table. I want to use a validation rule on the form so that information gets entered correctly. I have a datetime object that must be filled out in a non-traditional form so I just want to check the length and make sure it is equal to 16. I have the following in the form which does not work

`=Len([DISCHARGE DATETIME])=16`

But when I put the same rule in the table and not in the form it works just fine, any ideas?

Comment: Why? If you have a date time, just make sure it is not null, or insist on an input mask.

Comment: The input mask in Access is not of an acceptable form for when the data has to be uploaded to another source, I'll just use the rule on the table, it seems to work just fine there. The date time has to be of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM I do not see that input mask and I do not know how to make one.

Comment: It is not difficult to create an input mask, but if you think that a date / date time is in any format except number, you have a problem. A date is stored as an integer and a time as a decimal.

Comment: Periodically I have to take the data from the db and export it as a .csv and all datetimes must be in the form of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM when I upload the .csv file not in its serial number form

Comment: Is the field / column text or date? If it is date, it is up to you to create a query that formats the date correctly, and then export that.

Comment: I have it as `TEXT` it might just be easier for me to write the query

Comment: Much easier. Text is not a good format for a date.

Comment: alright, I'll just do that, thank you.

Comment: May the ask the purpose of entering this datetime? It just feels like something to be captured rather than entered. :)

Comment: There are many datetimes that need to be entered on the form and this is not something that can be captured as it is done in a retrospective manner where data is obtained from multiple systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates should be stored in date data types. In a lot of DBs the date data type is numeric. In MS Access it is a decimal, the integer portion is a date and the decimal a time. It is not difficult to create a query that uses the Format function to modify output to suit an application.

```
 SELECT Format(ThisDate,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") FROM ThisTable
```